# I am trying to do counts on multiple conditions and get them back as separate columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT COUNT("user_job".id) FROM "user_job" WHERE "user".job_title = 'Welder / Fitter') AS 
"WelderFitters"  
(SELECT COUNT("user_job".id)  AS "Welders"  FROM "user_job" WHERE "user".job_title = 
'Welder')
(SELECT COUNT("user_job".id)  AS "Fitters"  FROM "user_job" WHERE "user".job_title = 
'Fitter')
(SELECT COUNT("user_job".id)  AS "Helpers"  FROM "user_job" WHERE "user".job_title = 
'Helper')
JOIN "user" ON "user".id = "user_job".user_id 
JOIN "job" ON "job".id = "user_job".job_id
WHERE "job".id = 22;
```

//There are two joins involved. this doesn't work at all, but I think it illustrates what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like you can use `GROUP BY "user".job_title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  Your sample query suggests something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE u.job_title = 'Welder / Fitter') AS 
"WelderFitters",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE u.job_title = 'Welder') AS 
"Welders",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE u.job_title =  'Fitter') AS "Fitters",
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE u.job_title =  'Helper') AS "Helpers"
FROM "user" u JOIN
     "user_job" uj
     ON u.id = uj.user_id JOIN
     "job" j
     ON j.id = uj.job_id
WHERE j.id = 2;
```

However, I'm not sure if `job_title` is really in the `users` table.  It seems more likely it is in the `jobs` table.

Comment: It is in the users table, Thank you so much